# Asynchronous call using Spring webclient and just log the error without aborting the flow

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, webclient, reactive

I am trying to make an asynchronous call to a rest service using Spring webclient. I dont care if there is any exception during this call, but i want to just log if its successfull or failure (With http Status and details if Failure of course) but i want to continue to flow without stopping the flow. Can anyone suggest how can i improve below code:

In general , with regular try catch block I can do below:

```
try {
   restTemplate.execute(....);
} catch(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        //log and continue the flow....
}
```

What I came up is with below, but not sure if its the best way to execute a webclient as i am still trying to understand all the intermittent or terminal operations within it.

```
@Async
public void test() {
   webclient
   .post().uri("/urihere")
   .bodytoMono(requestBody)
//as exchange is deprecated
   .exchangeToMono(response -> {
       if(response.statusCode().is4xxHttpClientError) || response.statusCode().is5xxHttpServerError)) {
           //log with response body
       } else {
           //log successs response.
       }
   });
}
```

I understand that I don't need to do a `.block()` as I don't want to wait until the request is completed. But what I am trying to understand is the test method with web client call have the same functionality as in  with try catch ? Meaning, we just make a call and log the request /response but don't worry about the response?

Or am I doing anything incorrectly here. Need suggestions on above code for improvements or standards please (Is it fully reactive in nature with above code for the requirement is what I am trying to understand).

Comment: This should work fine. But there is one change which you would like to do is call retrieve() and then the rest of the code  ..something like this based on your usecase return webclient
   .post().uri("/urihere")  .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse ->
                        Mono.empty()
                )

Comment: Thank you. But what’s the advantage of using retrieve here over exchange? @Harry

Comment: Please ignore what i said..just realized that you are using exchangeToMono which is an equivalent and gives more control for handling the error.